# How to Determine view type (content, user taxonomy, etc)

Tags: views

I have inherited a site and I am trying to customise and replace some of the views. I have been told that there are views of various types, content, user, taxonomy, search index, etc. Where in the view after it has been created does it indicate the type of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already editing the view, it is also in the Title (so you don't have to navigate away from editing).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the /admin/structure/views views listing page, each view has a type attribute listed.